# Python 3.x - program repeats way too much

Tags: python, list, for-loop, python-3.x

I am writing a program that prints the letters on the left-column of a string. This is what I have:

```
str = '''Dear Sam:
From Egypt we went to Italy, and then took a trip to Germany, Holland and England.
We enjoyed it all but Rome and London most.
In Berlin we met Mr. John O. Young of Messrs. Tackico & Co., on his way to Vienna.
His address there is 147 upper Zeiss Street, care of Dr. Quincy W. Long.
Friday the 18th, we join C. N. Dazet, Esquire and Mrs. Dazet, and leave at 6:30 A.M. for Paris
on the 'Q. X.' Express and early on the morning on the 25th of June start for home on <br>the S. S. King.
Very sincerely yours,
Signature of writer'''

splitstr = list(str)
list_a = []
list_b = []

for i in splitstr:
    if i == '\n':
        list_a.append(list_b)
        list_b = []
    else:
        list_b.append(i)

    for i in list_a:
       left_column = list_b[:1]
       print(left_column)
       break
```

This code does print out the letters from the left column, but it prints it out too many times. The output should be something like

```
['D','F','W','I','H','F','o','V','S']
```

or it can be vertical, it does not matter.

Answer (score 3):

There's really no need for any of that, why not just do something like:

```
text = '''Dear Sam:
From Egypt we went to Italy, and then took a trip to Germany, Holland and England.
We enjoyed it all but Rome and London most.
In Berlin we met Mr. John O. Young of Messrs. Tackico & Co., on his way to Vienna.
His address there is 147 upper Zeiss Street, care of Dr. Quincy W. Long.
Friday the 18th, we join C. N. Dazet, Esquire and Mrs. Dazet, and leave at 6:30 A.M. for Paris
on the 'Q. X.' Express and early on the morning on the 25th of June start for home on the S. S. King.
Very sincerely yours,
Signature of writer
'''

print [line[0] for line in text.splitlines()]
```

```
['D', 'F', 'W', 'I', 'H', 'F', 'o', 'V', 'S']
```

Also, don't use `str` as a variable name since that's already the name of a built-in function.